# Rest API on weblogic - which will spawn threads based on request payload - how to control number of threads

Tags: java, multithreading, rest, spring-boot, weblogic12c

I am developing a Rest API using spring boot.
This rest api will be deployed on weblogic application server.
using Java 8

I am in the design phase so do not have any demonstratable code .

The API will receive a Request payload ( to approve Orders ) .
This Request payload can vary from 1 to 100000 OrderIds

For each of these orderIds I need to call a stored procedure in Oracle to approve the order.

The stored procedure has the business logic and it could take anywhere between a few seconds to minutes to respond back with a response.

To not keep the end user waiting am planning to implement this using "DeferredResult" from spring.

To achieve this I will be spawning off database call in a new thread using :
`ForkJoinPool.commonPool().submit(() -> {
   //do database call here 
}`

However I am not clear about how to control the number of threads spawned ?
Should I be worried about subsequent requests ( which I have no control over ) which could also lead to more threads being spawned ?

Comment: I'm no expert on Spring Boot but if I understand `ForkJoinPool` correctly it represents a pool of worker threads that you just submit tasks to. Thus you don't directly control the number of threads, you just submit more tasks.

Comment: ok thanks but then there would be a limit both on the JVM / weblogic and also on database ( number of concurrent requests it will handle ) - would that not be an issue ?

Comment: Well, that limit is already imposed by the hardware. If only 4 threads are able to run concurrently you can as well have just 4 which execute one task after another. A properly implemented [`ForkJoinTask`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask.html) should enable the pool to "suspend" blocking tasks (e.g. waiting for the db) and resume them later much like the scheduler can do for threads. However you'd have less overhead for context switches and thread creation.

Comment: If you're concerned about back pressure (i.e. tasks are created faster than they are executed and thus the queues fill up) you'd want to think about some scaling mechanism (scale out) - that would most likely to also require scaling of the database though.

Comment: regarding your comment about ''ForkJoinTask' was looking at the documentation you provided ( thanks ) did not find any parameter to define limit on number of threads to spawn or as you are stating that the limit would be imposed by hardware , so this is something that we as programmers cannot control ?

Comment: The end user will keep waiting, using `DeferredResult`or not. `DeferredResult` is just used to release the servlet container thread.  The connection is still open and Spring will set the result (and back to the end user) when the asynchronous process completed.

Comment: Thanks : so DeferredResult will help free the server up to process more incoming requests but end user client will still need to wait for results to be returned correct ?